# Is my data locked if deployed elsewhere as a REST service?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, image-service, mosaic-dataset

I have a number of Image Services published in ArcGIS for Server 10.3.1.
They are built from mosaic datasets in file geodatabases on a NAS.

The DEM tiles used in these services are required to built another mosaic dataset, on a larger scale.
However, when performing "Add Rasters" to the mosaic dataset I receive a General Function Error.  As if the data I am trying to add is locked in the GDB.

Do I need to shut down the REST services connected to the same rasters I am trying to add to a new mosaic dataset?

Setting up in an SDE is not an option at this time.

Comment: It shouldn't be. REST is stateless

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if there is a [Schema Lock](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/schema-locking.htm#GUID-BDC9A19E-3335-4F0E-805C-BA22868D72DD).

Else, if your service is published as a [Dynamic Service](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/about-dynamic-layers.htm) then there will be a lock on the data.

To correct the Dynamic Service Lock - publish the content as Cached or turn off the Machine and do your work then turn the Machine Back on(see image below).

[image]